# Problema con CORS en js

Tags: javascript, cors

Teno una pagina html que importa un fichero js. Y dentro una funcion:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
// set the provider you want from Web3.providers
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:22000"));
}

web3.eth.getBlock(18, function(error, result){
if(!error)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
else
    console.error(error);
 });
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me da error y no se como solventarlo.

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:22000/ (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')
>
> Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:22000/. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).

¿Alguna idea de como solventar esta falla?

Comment: El chrome da error de acceso a localhost para ello puedes intentar con la siguiente extensión: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: tan sencillo como eso... 20 minutos perdidos. Gracias postealo como respuesta para validarla. Puede que un futuro ayude a alquien.

Comment: @osiris85 Eso es un poco engañoso: el error es causado porque está accediendo a un sitio con JS descargado de otro.La extensión le soluciona el problema desactivando la seguridad en su navegador, pero no es una solución definitiva